# How to parse dictionary value with list of lists into a pydantic class?

Tags: python, dictionary, pydantic

How can I parse a Python dictionary into a pydantic class?

**Example:**

```
{"one":[["foo","bar"],["foo1","bar1"]]}
```

Comment: That is not an array of arrays. That is a list with lists.

Comment: Ooops!)))
Thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean by "describe a model"?

Comment: Assuming you want one of the instance's properties to look like that, don't you just want: `Dict[str, List[List[str]]]`?

Comment: @Mark likely, they mean to parse the dict into a pydantic class, so `List[List[str]]`, or on Python 3.9 + `list[list[str]]`

Comment: worked for me
class SuperClass(BaseModel):
    one: List[List[str]]

Answer (score 1):

The value is of type `List[List[str]`, so just type it as that.

```
In [1]: from pydantic import BaseModel

In [2]: from typing import List

In [3]: class X(BaseModel):
   ...:     one: List[List[str]]
   ...: 

In [4]: raw = {"one":[["foo","bar"],["foo1","bar1"]]}

In [5]: obj = X(**raw)

In [6]: obj
Out[6]: X(one=[['foo', 'bar'], ['foo1', 'bar1']])

In [7]: obj.one
Out[7]: [['foo', 'bar'], ['foo1', 'bar1']]
```